# Cursor declaration in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql-update, cursor, fetch, amazon-redshift

My aim is to parse the first table check if the ID exists in the second table, then do some updates.

The first table runs in loop and parses each row in the second table to update or give the output.

Here the code that I used:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c1 FOR (SELECT pnr,agrnumber,pnrcreatedate FROM test2_view_table);
r1 c1%ROWTYPE;
CURSOR c2 FOR (SELECT pnr,ano,pcdt FROM sdh_ticket_test2_update);
r2 c2%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
 FOR r1 IN c1
 LOOP
  FOR r2 IN c2
  LOOP
   IF (r1.pnr = r2.pnr and r2.pnrcreatedate is null  and 
r1.agrnumber=r2.ano)
   THEN
     c++
   else if (r1.pnr = r2.pnr and r2.agrnumber is null and  
r1.pcdt=r2.pnrcreatedate)
  THEN
      a++   -- continue to the next iteration of the outer loop
    -- as we have a match
    GOTO continue;
   END IF;
  END LOOP;
  -- we can only reach that point if there was no match
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(c));
  <<continue>>
  NULL;

 END LOOP;
END;
```

For the declaration of cursor in redshift as above. its throwing me the following error.

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "c1"
```

Please let me know if there is any solution.

Comment: Redshift doesn't support cursors as they are very inefficient on large data volumes. You need two separate queries - one for update based on the join, and another select join.

Comment: Can you state at a high-level what your function is attempting to do? If so, we might be able to suggest an alternate way of doing it without having to write code and loops.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of row-by-row processing is not suitable for *any* modern database. Just define the logic in a SQL query (or queries) and let the DB figure out how to do the actual work.

In this case you can do the entire comparison in one step. You could actually rewrite this as a single `UPDATE`.

```
BEGIN

UPDATE sdh_ticket_test2_update
SET    pnrcreatedate = c1.pcdt
FROM      test2_view_table c1
LEFT JOIN sdh_ticket_test2_update c2
       ON c1.pnr = c2.pnr 
      AND c1.agrnumber = c2.ano
WHERE c2.pnrcreatedate IS NULL 
;

UPDATE sdh_ticket_test2_update
SET    ano = c1.agrnumber
FROM      test2_view_table c1
LEFT JOIN sdh_ticket_test2_update c2
       ON c1.pnr = c2.pnr 
      AND c1.pcdt = c2.pnrcreatedate
WHERE c2.agrnumber IS NULL 
;

COMMIT
```